# How to check the mouse holded a second or millisecond on a marker with google map event listener?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google map mouseover event Listener for call a function like below. I need only exicute the function, if the user holded the mouse more than a second on a maker.

`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {`

```
        OnMouseoverMarker(marker);

    });
```

Any quick solution?

Comment: So how do you think you should go about doing that?

Comment: I want to excite the function if the user hold the mouse at least some milliseconds on the maker. Any method available like jQuery .delay() ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout` to call the desired function with a delay.
On mouseout use `clearTimeout` to clear the timeout.

Example:

```
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(){
            var that=this;
            clearTimeout(this.timer)
            this.timer=setTimeout(function(){OnMouseoverMarker(that);},1000)
            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this,'mouseout',
                                              function(){clearTimeout(this.timer);});
         });
```