# How to check mouse holded some sec on a element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How we can check mouse holed some seconds on an element.

Means that the function should execute only if the user holds the mouse more than minimum seconds(eg:3 sec) on an element.

Many of the answers found in the stack, but that solutions are delaying the execution, but I want to check mouse holed or not, If yes, execute the function else don't make any action.

Already asked same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332682/how-to-check-the-mouse-holded-a-second-or-millisecond-on-a-marker-with-google-ma/18335234?noredirect=1#18335234) before, but not yet get the answer exactly what I looking

Is it possible?

Comment: Generally there's not such event. You'll have to simulate it yourself. doesn't mousedown event work for you?

Comment: There seems to be an answer in that thread which looks correct to me...

Comment: Here's an example I coded up in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7YtNS/

Comment: ... and [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLZa7/1)

Comment: you want that event to fire when the CURSOR IS HOVERED or the MOUSEKEY IS HELD DOWN?

Comment: ... and here's [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLZa7/2/) that demonstrates how bored I am right now!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out in the real scenario

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for this, here if a `div` gets hover and hold mouse for at least 3 seconds then do your stuff like below

```
var myTimeout;

$('div').mouseenter(function() {
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        alert("do your stuff now");
    }, 3000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

here's a custom jquery function for that

```
$.fn.mouseHover = function(time, callback){
  var timer;

  $(this).on("mouseover", function(e){
      timer = setTimeout(callback.bind(this, e), time);
  }.bind(this)).on("mouseout", function(e){
      clearTimeout(timer);
  })
};

$('#my-element').mouseHover(3000, function(){ alert("WHOOPWhOOP");});
```

just in case OP meant click and hold.

```
$.fn.mouseHold = function(time, callback) {
    var timer;
    $(this).on("mousedown", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        timer = setTimeout(callback.bind(this, e), time);
    }.bind(this)).on("mouseup", function(e){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    })
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsbin.com/huhagiju/1/

Answer (score 1):

Should be easy enough:

```
$('.your-element').on('mousedown', function(event) {
    var $that = $(this);
    // This timeout will run after 3 seconds.
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        if ($that.data('mouse_down_start') != null) {
            // If it's not null, it means that the user hasn't released the click yet
            // so proceed with the execution.
            runMouseDown(event, $that);

            // And remove the data.
            $(that).removeData('mouse_down_start');
        }
    }, 3000);

    // Add the data and the mouseup function to clear the data and timeout
    $(this)
        .data('mouse_down_start', true)
        .one('mouseup', function(event) {
            // Use .one() here because this should only fire once.
            $(this).removeData('mouse_down_start');
            clearTimeout(t);
        });
});

function runMouseDown(event, $that) {
    // do whatever you need done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Checkout](http://jsfiddle.net/9f9ZN/4/)

### Logic

- The mousedown handler records the click start time
- The mouseup handler records the mouse up time and calculate time difference if it exceeds 3 secs then alerts the time else alerts less than 3 seconds

### HTML

```
<p>Press mouse and release here.</p>
```

### Jquery

```
 var flag, flag2;


    $( "p" )
      .mouseup(function() {
        $( this ).append( "<span style='color:#f00;'>Mouse up.</span>" );
            flag2 = new Date().getTime();
       var passed = flag2 - flag;
          if(passed>='3000')
              alert(passed);
          else
               alert("left before");

           console.log(passed); //time passed in milliseconds     
      })
      .mousedown(function() {
        $( this ).append( "<span style='color:#00f;'>Mouse down.</span>" );
          flag = new Date().getTime();

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all about logic.

You just have a variable to tell you if you have been listening on this for some time like 3 seconds.

If you are listening for more than that, which is not possible since you should had reset it, so then reset it. Else you do your work.

```
var mySpecialFunc = function() { alert("go go go..."); };

var lastTime = 0;

var main_id = "some_id" ;// supply the id of  a div over which to check mouseover

document.getElementById(main_id).addEventListener("mouseover",function(e) {
    var currTime = new Date().getTime();
    var diffTime = currTime - lastTime;
    if(diffTime > 4000) {
        // more than 4 seconds reset the lastTime
        lastTime = currTime;
        alert("diffTime " + diffTime);
         return ;   
    }

    if(diffTime > 3000) {
       // user had mouseover for too long
       lastTime = 0; 
       mySpecialFunc("info");
    } 

    // else do nothing.
});
```

This is a basic code, i think you can improve and adjust according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code (with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLZa7/6/)) that does what you want...

(*it also shows how bored I am tonight*)

```
var props = {
    1000: { color: 'red',    msg: 'Ready' },
    2000: { color: 'yellow', msg: 'Set' },
    3000: { color: 'green' , msg: 'Go!' }
};

var handles = [];
var $d = $('#theDiv');

$d.mouseenter(function () {
    $.each(props, function (k, obj) {
        handles[k] = setTimeout(function () {
            changeStuff($d, obj);    
        }, k);
    });    
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $.each(handles, function (i, h) {
        clearTimeout(h);
    });
    reset($d);
});

function reset($d) {
    $d.css('backgroundColor', 'orange');
    $d.text('Hover here...');
}

function changeStuff($node, o) {
    $node.css('backgroundColor', o.color);
    $node.text(o.msg);
}
```